# Limiting Visits to Wildcard Subdomains in PHP

Tags: php, apache-2.2

Wondering if there are any good ideas on how to make a feature to limit site visits (per month). It is for an app that uses client-based subdomains, or "wildcards". My initial thoughts are that the visit-count logic will have to be within PHP. I am thinking once a limit is hit (for the month), a config file is overwritten for Apache, disallowing anymore traffic to the particular subdomain. This way, any type of extreme traffic basically bounces off the server, instead of getting to the app itself, and initiating any of the logic/SQL queries.

I would anticipate a cron would reset the Apache file, and the view counts in the database. What do you think for a simple count limiter? Any other ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I woudn't complicate this with modifying apache config files. If you put the check at the beginning of your code things should work fine.